# custom marker icon not showing up in static map default red marker only showing in the map..I have used the icon from google drive

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have loaded the custom marker icon from drive..
this is my url:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&markers=icon:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_-nl7XFeIUSfJPyhtJjxr_ETYGYKaS_M/view|40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

[image: static map with incorrect icon]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us code you wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are providing for the icon: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_-nl7XFeIUSfJPyhtJjxr_ETYGYKaS_M/view` is not an image (it is a google drive "page").

If I link to the image on that page: `https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/uCOumviUOK9FeSH8d0pg3pW7CSj_-xRYLscegax5LefENROwlIRLzrxezS1U_7jM5MrFVDSJ9d4nKMWcyFak=w1280-h918`; it works for me (not sure if that will never change)

URL: `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&markers=icon:https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/uCOumviUOK9FeSH8d0pg3pW7CSj_-xRYLscegax5LefENROwlIRLzrxezS1U_7jM5MrFVDSJ9d4nKMWcyFak=w1280-h918|40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400`

[image: static map with custom icon]